# How to get Serilog to use custom enricher from json config file

Tags: c#, json, .net, configuration, serilog

I wish to use formatted UTC timestamps in my Serilog output.
I have written a custom enricher that works fine when called from C# code.

```
public class UtcTimestampEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory pf)
    {
        logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(pf.CreateProperty("UtcTimestamp", logEvent.Timestamp.UtcDateTime));
    }
}

....

var loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration().MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .Enrich.With(new UtcTimestampEnricher())
    .Filter
    .ByIncludingOnly( expr) // need this .Filter to ensure that 
              // Serilog.Filters.Expressions.dll gets loaded, else filters in config file get ignored
    .WriteTo.Console(
        outputTemplate: "[{UtcTimestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff} {Level:u3} {Subsystem}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
        restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information);

Log.Logger = loggerConfig.CreateLogger();
```

Now I wish to use the utcTimestamp enricher while configuring the logger from my custom json config file.

```
var jsonLogconfiguration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile(logconfigFname)
    .Build();

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(jsonLogconfiguration)
    .CreateLogger();
```

My json config file

```json
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.Console"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "{UtcTimestamp:yyyy,MM,dd,HH,mm,ss,fff },{Level:u3},{Subsystem},{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" , "UtcTimestampEnricher"], 
    "Filter": [
      {
        "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
        "Args": {
          "expression": "Subsystem = 'Config'  or  Subsystem = 'Admin' "
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The message I get on the console: ( I have previously called serilog selflog to get serilog debug messages about itself)

```
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Console.WriteLine(msg));
```

Serilog debug output.

```
2020-06-05T09:34:01.3898891Z Unable to find a method called UtcTimestampEnricher. Candidate methods are:
Serilog.LoggerConfiguration When(Serilog.Configuration.LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration, System.String, System.Action`1[Serilog.Configuration.LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration])
Serilog.LoggerConfiguration With(Serilog.Configuration.LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration, Serilog.Core.ILogEventEnricher)
Serilog.LoggerConfiguration FromLogContext(Serilog.Configuration.LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration)
```

I got similar output when I tried to use

```json
"Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" , "UtcTimestamp"],
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Even though the problem has been already solved I want to put my 2 cents regarding this problem.

Whenever you create a custom `Enricher` you have two options how you can register that:

- Either via code
- or via configuration

### Via Code

#### Enricher

```cs
public class UtcTimestampEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory pf)
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

#### Registration

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.With<UtcTimestampEnricher>()
    .CreateLogger()
```

### Via Configuration

#### Enricher

```cs
public class UtcTimestampEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory pf)
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

#### Registration helper

```cs
public static class LoggingExtensions
{
    public static LoggerConfiguration WithUtcTimestamp(
        this LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration enrich)
    {
        if (enrich == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(enrich));

        return enrich.With<UtcTimestampEnricher>();
    }
}
```

#### Registration

```json
{
  "Serilog": {
    ...,
    "Using": [ "Your.Assembly.Name" ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithUtcTimestamp" ]
  },
```

So, as you can see what you need to register is the registration helper method (not the enricher itself) in case of configuration based setup.

Comment: Thanks for this, makes it clearer, I thinks the docs are a bit thin in this area

Comment: Is there a way how to implement dependency injection within the helper `WithUtcTimestamp` to inject for example `IConfiguration` interface?

Comment: @Muflix I haven't tested it but I think all you need to do is to add the IConfiguration as a parameter to the extension method. Like this: https://github.com/trenoncourt/serilog-enrichers-aspnetcore-httpcontext/blob/master/src/Serilog.Enrichers.AspnetcoreHttpcontext/LoggerEnrichmentConfigurationExtensions.cs

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured this out, and could get the custom enricher to work by specifying it in C# code

```
var jsonLogconfiguration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile(logconfigFname)
    .Build();

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.With(new UtcTimestampEnricher()) // is necessary
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(jsonLogconfiguration)
    .CreateLogger()
```

and removing the enrich with from the config file

```
"Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ],
```