# CallerMemberAttributes as an enricher

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, serilog, seq

I am looking for a way to turn CallerMemberAttributes into a custom enricher but I can't figure out how to do that.
I currently have it set like this, but I don't want to put .Here() at each log.

```
public static ILogger Here(this ILogger logger,
        [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
        {
            return logger
                .ForContext("MemberName", memberName)
                .ForContext("FilePath", sourceFilePath)
                .ForContext("LineNumber", sourceLineNumber);
        }
```

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62212569/how-to-get-serilog-to-use-custom-enricher-from-json-config-file

Comment: I did take a look at a bunch of different sources, there was a few examples of making custom enrichers but they didn't help to apply it to implementing them with CallerMemberAttributes. I might also be doing them wrong, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Some genius mod deleted my comment which was a search link for a github search for `serilog CallerMemberAttribute` - there are lots of variations on the above. AFAIK there is no official package (and I would argue that a good message should not rely on line numbers - the tutorial at serilog.net is at pains to convey that message IMO)